# Multiple DataTemplates with UWP MapItemsControl

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

I have a `MapControl` in UWP:

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="BikeMap" ZoomLevel="17" Center="{Binding CenterPoint, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapItems" ItemsSource="{Binding BikePoints}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BikePointTemplate}"/>
</maps:MapControl>
```

and am adding MapElements using XAML data templates, my ItemsSource is a list of simple objects.

But, UWP doesn't seem to provide a way to specify the `DataType` of a `DataTemplate` and the `MapItemsControl` doesn't have a property for setting a `DataTemplateSelector`.

Does anyone know how I can use multiple data templates with the MapItemsControl and have the relevent data template selected based on the object type within the ItemsSource?

Comment: It's hard to believe that the UWP MapItemsControl is not derived from ItemsControl. You may perhaps choose a different map library where the MapItemsControl is actually an ItemsControl with a working ItemTemplateSelector, like [this one](https://xamlmapcontrol.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hello @JayZuo-MSFT I haven't tried it yet as have been busy. I will get round to it soon! Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MapItemsControl Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapitemscontrol.aspx) does not have a property for setting [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector). To achieve what you want, we can take advantage of [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) by setting it as the template content in [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate.aspx) and then using [ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector.aspx) property to set [DataTemplateSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector).

Following is a simple sample:

XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="UWPApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:Maps="using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:UWPApp"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="GreenDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Background="Green">
                <TextBlock Margin="5"
                           Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"
                           Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5"
                           FontSize="20"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="RedDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Background="Red">
                <TextBlock Margin="5"
                           Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}"
                           Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5"
                           FontSize="20"
                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" GreenTemplate="{StaticResource GreenDataTemplate}" RedTemplate="{StaticResource RedDataTemplate}" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Maps:MapControl x:Name="MyMap" MapServiceToken="MapServiceToken">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MyMapItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl>
        </Maps:MapControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code-Behind:

```cs
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate GreenTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate RedTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item is GreenPOI)
            {
                return GreenTemplate;
            }

            return RedTemplate;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class POI
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
}

public class GreenPOI : POI { }

public class RedPOI : POI { }
```

This is just for example. In the sample, I used two data template with different background and I create a custom `DataTemplateSelector` which can choose `DataTemplate` based on the object type. And if you have several object types, you can also refer to this answer: [How to associate view with viewmodel or multiple DataTemplates for ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293716/5506161)

Comment: This was a great solution however the map control won't add more items after initial bind and render... I cannot seem to figure out why. Only the initial items are drawn.

Comment: Ah ha, [new ObservableCollection<object>] fails to update but [new ObservableCollection<POI>] works... not sure why that is.