# MVVM – Hierarchies & Navigation Implicit Binding for UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

Somewhat I've been trying to follow this MVVM tutorial using Hierarchies and navigation:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_hierarchies_and_navigation.htm

I've done so far most of the tutorial, but when it comes to UWP it seems that Implicit binding is not available for UWP, so I can't replicate this tutorial, because even though I've used x:DataType with x:Key that the compiler asks for an x:key attribute in order to bind views with viewmodel, all I get is the fullname of my viewmodel instead of being able to see the actual content.

So can somebody help me how can I use hierarchies properly in UWP using Plain MVVM pattern without the help of tools such as MVVM Light or MVVM Cross.

I'll leave you the code I have so far for a UWP app:

```
<Page
x:Class="MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.MainPageView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo"
xmlns:views="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.Views"
xmlns:viewmodel="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.ViewModel"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<!--Anytime the current view model is set to an instance of a CustomerListViewModel,
it will render out a CustomerListView with the ViewModel is hooked up. It’s an order ViewModel,
it'll render out OrderView and so on.

We now need a ViewModel that has a CurrentViewModel property and some logic and commanding
to be able to switch the current reference of ViewModel inside the property.-->
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:MainPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodel:CustomerListViewModel">
        <views:CustomerListView/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrderTemplate" x:DataType="viewmodel:OrderViewModel">
        <views:OrderView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="NavBar"
          Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Button Content="Customers"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="customers"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Button Content="Orders"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="orders"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="MainContent"
          Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>      
</Grid>
```

as you can see may main trouble are at my Page. Resources I guess with my binding at

because that line of code is not getting access to the actual content of my views.

this is my viewmodel for my main view:

```
namespace MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.ViewModel
{
    /*Derive all of your ViewModels from BindableBase class.*/
    public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            NavCommand = new MyCommand<string>(OnNavigation);
        }

        private CustomerListViewModel _customerListViewModel = new CustomerListViewModel();

        private OrderViewModel _orderViewModel = new OrderViewModel();

        private BindableBase _currentViewModel;

        public BindableBase CurrentViewModel
        {
            get
            {
                return _currentViewModel;
            }

            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _currentViewModel, value);
            }
        }

        public MyCommand<string> NavCommand { get; private set; }

        private void OnNavigation(string destination)
        {
            switch (destination)
            {
                case "orders":
                    {
                        CurrentViewModel = _orderViewModel;
                        break;
                    }
                case "customers":
                default:
                    CurrentViewModel = _customerListViewModel;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally this is my helper bindable class:

```
namespace MVVMHeirarchiesDemo
{
    /*The main idea behind this class is to encapsulate the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
     * and provide helper methods to the derived class so that they can easily trigger the appropriate notifications.
     * Following is the implementation of BindableBase class.*/
    public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void SetProperty<T>(ref T member, T val, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(member, val))
                return;

            member = val;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out with this one.

Comment: For this to work in UWP I guess you'll need to implement a `DataTemplateSelector` in the `ContentTemplateSelector` property of the `ContentControl` element, since you are following a WPF tutorial. Keep in mind that not every XAML _logic_ from WPF will just work in UWP.

Comment: Yes, i have Just found a DataTemplateSelector question, ill apply it right now. Thanks man!!! That is the proper way to solve this in UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well It took me a while but i was able to understand how to use DataTemplateSelector class, it turns out that this work around fit nicely to my problem since there is no implicit binding for UWP.
So if you are exploring UWP there isnt IMPLICIT BINDING you have to use explicit binding in order to make this specific problem work.

So this was my solution, I still use my BindableBase because it help me to choose the proper ViewModel for the View i'm calling, so there is no need to change it.

firstable I've created a Template class so I can retrieve the properties that will help me work with ExplicitBinding:

```
public class Template
{
    public string DataType { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate DataTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'll use a Collection but I'll use a Facade Pattern on this one, I kind love patterns are fun and elegant.

```
public class TemplateCollection : Collection<Template>
{
}
```

Then I've used a class by another answer that helps me to reuse it to solve my problem:

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public TemplateCollection Templates { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Template> _templateCache { get; set; }

    public MyDataTemplateSelector()
    {

    }

    private void InitTemplateCollection()
    {
        _templateCache = Templates.ToList();
    }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (_templateCache == null)
        {
            InitTemplateCollection();
        }

        if (item != null)
        {
            var dataType = item.GetType().ToString();

            var match = _templateCache.Where(m => m.DataType == dataType).FirstOrDefault();

            if (match != null)
            {
                return match.DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplateCore(item, container);
    }
}
```

this class can be found here: [How to associate view with viewmodel or multiple DataTemplates for ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252915/how-to-associate-view-with-viewmodel-or-multiple-datatemplates-for-viewmodel/33293716#33293716)

just I dont like to steal credits, but I did learned from this answer and my partner sugesstion MLavoie.

so this is my Fix view thanks to this I'm able to use navigation and also created a Hierarchical MVVM Pattern.

```
<Page
x:Class="MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.MainPageView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo"
xmlns:dtempsltor="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.Templates"
xmlns:views="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.Views"
xmlns:viewmodel="using:MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.ViewModel"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<!--Anytime the current view model is set to an instance of a CustomerListViewModel,
it will render out a CustomerListView with the ViewModel is hooked up. It’s an order ViewModel,
it'll render out OrderView and so on.

We now need a ViewModel that has a CurrentViewModel property and some logic and commanding
to be able to switch the current reference of ViewModel inside the property.-->
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:MainPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <dtempsltor:TemplateCollection2 x:Key="templates">
        <dtempsltor:Template DataType="MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.ViewModel.CustomerListViewModel">
            <dtempsltor:Template.DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:CustomerListViewModel">
                    <views:CustomerListView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dtempsltor:Template.DataTemplate>
        </dtempsltor:Template>
        <dtempsltor:Template DataType="MVVMHeirarchiesDemo.ViewModel.OrderViewModel">
            <dtempsltor:Template.DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:OrderViewModel">
                    <views:OrderView/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dtempsltor:Template.DataTemplate>
        </dtempsltor:Template>
    </dtempsltor:TemplateCollection2>
    <dtempsltor:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector" 
                                       Templates="{StaticResource templates}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid x:Name="NavBar"
          Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Button Content="Customers"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="customers"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Button Content="Orders"
                Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
                CommandParameter="orders"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="MainContent"
          Grid.Row="1">
        <ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"
                        Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>      
</Grid>
```

thanks for those who helped me enlight myself it was great, to be able to solve it with some hints and also felt good to be able to solve it, I kinda love to code in C# and Xaml.