# Register two classes in a container with same interface in Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using **Unity.Mvc5** for Dependency Injection.

I have two classes which are implementing single interface. 
For example refer below screen shot

[image]

Now when I am injecting it in Controller's constructor for initializing Interface instance and after initializing when calling function of test then it is calling method of last registered class. please refer below screen shot

[image: Image 2]

Comment: What is the question? You have described the default behavior of the container where last registered wins.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921451/5233410